# How did "adult" themed shows get on CITV?

Tags: content-rating

Back in the 90s there were some shows on Children's ITV (CITV) that had some fairly adult themes.

Round the Bend was quite notorious, with many of the jokes doubtless going over the heads of the young viewers. Some were simply references to things they wouldn't have known, such as the Terry Wogan parody "Wo-gan the Barbarian", and some went as far as sexual innuendo.

I remember another show (but not its name) set in a school where the teacher accidentally played a pornographic VHS tape. A scantily clad man carried a scantily clad woman over to a bed before the stop button was pressed, while the class reacted with glee.

At the time I thought it was all hilarious but looking back I'm kind of amazed how any of this got broadcast in the first place. Did CITV have lax standards and checks on content at that time? Were the producers of the shows deliberately trying to sneak it past them?

Comment: From experience of living in communist country with very strict censorship: a) if there is any form of censorship you want to try with how much you can get (for the sake of it) b)you put ridiciolous amount of thngs to censor so things you don't want to be censored would look bleak in comparision. Sometimes it work other way round.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY I don’t believe the U.K. has ever been a communist country though.

Comment: @Darren but they had censorship. It might be mere play "will they let sex joke through if we mention IRA?"

Comment: It's nowhere near as complex as that @SZCZERZOKŁY .... the producers are just playing with the boundaries of what they can get away with, because its fun for them to do and the kids will love it.  Eventually Round the Bend was cancelled because it was deemed unsuitable for kids by some lobby groups.

Comment: However it's worth pointing out that it took non-governmental lobby groups involvement to pressure ITV into cancelling the show

Comment: I should add some video of Round the Bend. Anyone know what the other show was because that's an even better example?